# How to calculate the best reason of a topic with the following data…

Tags: java, data-analysis, factor-analysis

I want to get/calculate the reason of a topic that why became such hot topic between the users.
This topic is a short video which is made by a singer/actor and upload to the server and there is a mobile app which this video can be watch in, and the data that can be made by the users (fans) are these：

- **Brows** (will be made by every brows this video (multi/users))
- **Like** (one/user)
- **Share**
- **Add to favorite**
- **Challenge** (to challenge him/her about this video)
- **Reward** (user can reward him/her by paying)

**Now** what can be the best way to calculate/analyze the reason from these data that why this topic became such popular between users? Or how can these data help us to analyze the result?

**Update:**

Besides the above data, I can also have the **IP Address** of the users.

**Example:**

Topic "Come to dance" can have the following data:

Brows-----Like-----Share-----Favorite-----Challenge-----Reward

45600-----145------4180------120-------------7----------------434